# Organize long animation

Tags: animation

I sense there is an obvious way to do this that I have somehow missed.

I´m helping a client doing an instructional animation showing how to assemble a swimming pool, showing all the steps from digging the pit to a final beauty shot of the finished thing.

The way I have done it so far is appending all the models and organizing them in collections. Then I've just key framed everything in the time line. This works but as soon as the client ask for something to be changed it's a tedious nightmare. For instance there is literally thousands of screws that need to go inte right order.

How should I have done this to make it ass efficient as possible and to make it as easy as possible to change the order in wich things are happening?

If there are a tutorial, article or subject I should look into, the please direct me to it.

Many thanks in advance!
/Björn

Comment: Try looking at tutorials about Blender's NLA (Nonlinear Animation) editor. That's what it's for! [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/introduction.html) is the Blender manual introduction to the NLA but there are many detailed YT videos showing how to use it online.

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you. That’s another blender topic I never learned but I need to. I hope I can be ass efficient at it soon (yes, Bjorn, I’m ribbing you).

Comment: Blender is full of surprises, but the NLA has been there for years! :^)